# ROS Answers SE migration: rviz ardrone

Tags: rviz, ardrone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys, I am trying to get the video feed of ardrone to the rviz

The situation is that Rviz is not able to get the camera feed from the ardrone.
It says the following:

Camerainfo: no camerainfo received   on [ /ardrone/camera_info] topic may not exsist
transform : For frame []: Fixed Frame[/world] does not exist
image topic: /ardrone/image_raw

but when i execute

> > rostopic list

I get

/ardrone/camera_info

/ardrone/image_raw

/ardrone/image_raw/compressed

/ardrone/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions

/ardrone/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates

/ardrone/image_raw/theora

/ardrone/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions

/ardrone/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates

/ardrone/land

/ardrone/navdata

/ardrone/reset

/ardrone/takeoff

/ardrone/togglecam

/cmd_vel

/rosout

/rosout_agg

The topic ardrone/camera_info does exist  but RVIZ is not able to see that.Like wise this is the case when i tried to access the usb cam or system integrated cam.In all of the cases the rviz says that it is void of camera info topic even though its running clear

any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12570/rviz-ardrone/) by [metal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1575/metal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 174 on 2012-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The reason is that the display parameter chosen should be "IMAGE" and choose the topic "ardron e" from the drop down and the image will be displayed in a window.

---

Originally posted by [metal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1575/metal/) with karma: 174 on 2012-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-01-15**:
The Camera display assumes a camera_info topic is available and attempts to overall other data onto the image using the CameraInfo. The Image display type does not use CameraInfo and is suitable for displaying raw, unrectified images (similar to the image_view tool).